# PHP get the result of each Multidimensional array separated

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, sum

I have Multidimensional array that genereted from database and would like to some itm2+itm3 for each array and get the total of Multidimensional array like:

`array 5 = 1740`
`array 6 = 2700`

this is a part of my Multidimensional array:

```
$arrays = Array
 (
  [5] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Objectd(
                [itm1] => 19
                [itm2] => 500
                [itm3] => 100
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object(
                [itm1] => 20
                [itm2] => 700
                [itm3] => 100
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object(
                [itm1] => 21
                [itm2] => 240
                [itm3] => 100
            )
    )
  [6] => Array(
        [0] => stdClass Object(
                [itm1] => 22
                [itm2] => 1500
                [itm3] => 100
            )
        [1] => stdClass Object(
                [itm1] => 23
                [itm2] => 1000
                [itm3] => 100
            )
    )
 )
```

Comment: What have you tried? What errors did you get? If no errors displayed please post your PHP error Log. Thank you

Comment: Hi Mark, I'm new in php and found difficulty to get this result :)

Comment: It's hard to help you fix something if nothing is broken

Answer (score 0):

I had to focus a little more :)
the solution is:

```
            foreach($array as $key1=>$val1){
                $sum_to_values =0;
                $sum_to_array =0;
                foreach($val1 as $val2){
                    $sum_to_values = $val2->itm2 * $val2->itm3;
                    $sum_to_array +=$sum_to_values;
                }echo $sum_to_array.'<br/>';
            }
```

thank you!